# Limits on Denmark's permanent residency

Tags: residency, denmark

What is required to remain a permanent resident of Denmark? I'm a U.S. citizen considering a long-term move. If I were to earn permanent residency and then be called back to the U.S., how long could I stay away before losing that status? I've done a fair amount of searching but haven't seen it addressed.

Comment: Hi planarian. This site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have a whole other site for living abroad long term, called [expatriates.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/Your-situation-is-changing/Work/Lapse-dispensation) contains an answer for you:

> ## What if I hold a permanent residence permit?
>
> Other rules apply if the Danish Immigration Service has granted you a permanent residence permit based on former permits issued by SIRI.
>
> In this case, **your residence permit will lapse automatically if you give up your Danish address or stay abroad for more than 12 successive months.** This applies even though you keep being registered at a Danish address in the CPR.

Comment: Thanks, I could have spent hours wandering through that site without finding it.